# Javascript to print div inside external html page

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am using the following javascript code to print a div layer from a webpage. Is there a way that this can be modified to print this div from from another page (for example print.php) not the one that is open in the moment ?

```
<script>function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
} </script>
```

and the link to make it work is: `<a href="#" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')">`

Comment: can you post your html markup?

Comment: suere the link which is triggering the script is : <a href="#" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')">

Comment: I believe you are asking for AJAX. Go read about it for a while then come back and refine your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking whether it's possible to print a DIV in another page.

If this is the question ,it is possible given these two page have some relation,so that the other page can get reference of the content page.

For example ,  print.php opens the content page by using window.open. Or , print.php is the parent page of the content page.